Extra work and no pay?
I've recently started a new internship program. They pay me waaay less than supposed to citing that they are a non-profit organization. I have been okay with that since I need the experience. I have no contract and no job description, no guidance on how to do my job or their expectations. So I've been using weekends to upskill and do odd jobs to get more money.
Issue: they want me to regularly work weekends with no extra pay. But promise some days off as compensation.
Question: how do I address this without sounding ungrateful?
Side note:I am much more qualified than the position requires.

"How do I address this without sounding ungrateful?" - What are you grateful for? That they are taking advantage of you? Leave and find someone who will pay you and not try and exploit you.

“But promise some days off as compensation.” - Does this mean your working more than your scheduled hours? If so only you can decide to do that. Don’t work for free You are looking for a permanent position, when you are not working, right?

What country is this?  In many jurisdictions paying less than the minimum wage is illegal.

how do I address this without sounding ungrateful? - Ungrateful for what? Being an indentured servant? Why not just find an actual job rather than this internship? Also, have you considered simply telling them no?

“No” is a complete sentence.

"Promise some days off as compensation".  If you do decide to take them up on this, don't let them these "some days" be vague days in the far future, or you might find that they never happen.  Be specific.  If you agree to work every Saturday, tell them that you need every single Monday off.  Or if you agree to work 5 Saturdays in November, tell them that you need, say, Nov 11 - Nov 15 specifically off.

I firmly disagree that this question is a duplicate of "Underpaid and overworked, how should I approach my boss?" First of all the OP has no working contract, they are doing an internship, secondly here we are talking about an  abuse of power, working for free, compared to asking for a fairer pay rise for extra work done. Related, yes, but not identical.

Thank you much all. I'm approaching other companies already. Seems like if issues like these aren't addressed early, they turn into disaster. Good insights from you all.

How could you not have a contract? All jobs, event unpaid internships require a contract and you need to be insured. Are you working legally in that company?

You could politely tell them that you reserve your weekends to work other jobs that pay, and cannot switch that time into work that doesn't pay. You might suggest you're open to the idea but simply need them to address the financial aspect somehow, as "days off instead" isn't appealing to you.
